# C++ syntax of { }

Tags: c++, syntax

Still don't understand such enclosed code. What { } actually means and what does it do ? From time to time see the syntax like this and wonder if it's compiler specific or c++ stuff:

```
{
             zmq::message_t request((void *)message.c_str(), message.length(), NULL);

             std::cout << "Sending " << message << std::endl;
             socket.send(request);
          }
```

Here is the whole code sample:

```
int main(void){
    try
    {
   zmq::context_t context(1);
   std::cout << "Connecting to echo server" << std::endl;
   zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REQ); 
   socket.connect("tcp://localhost:50013"); 

   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << "Hello ";
   for(int request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 10; ++request_nbr)
   {
      ss << request_nbr;
      std::string message(ss.str());

      {
         zmq::message_t request((void *)message.c_str(), message.length(), NULL);

         std::cout << "Sending " << message << std::endl;
         socket.send(request);
      } 

      {
         zmq::message_t reply;
         socket.recv(&reply);

         std::cout << "Received ";
         std::for_each((char*)reply.data(), (char*)reply.data() + reply.size(),
            [](char c){ std::cout << c;});
         std::cout << std::endl;
      } // 11
   }

   zmq::message_t request(0);
   socket.send(request);
   std::cout << "Sending empty message and terminating" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Opition: The author of the code felt that there was some logical grouping to the statements but could not be bothered extracting them into functions.  The scoping also does RAII.  Comments in the code would also help.

Comment: As @Richard said, could be grouping, could be RAII for `zmq::message_t request` will go out of scope at the `}`

Comment: Ahh, than it's just to enclose the variable scope in code flow where no logical function calls necessery. Otherwise there should set function call to enclose that variable scope. Right ?

Comment: Yea it's a matter of variable scoping. So that what's in the blocks are localized or exists only when execution is in the block.

Comment: @RichardCritten: There's no reason to extract those blocks as functions. For one thing, they refer to declarations in the function, which would have to be passed as parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Those curly braces in your example code are used to start a new scope. Sometimes it's interesting to start a new scope block so that you automatically deallocate local scoped variables when you leave the block. New scope blocks can also be used to shadow homonymous variables with a larger scope.